# How do I create a data type that increments in .75 but has a default value of 3.2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I create a data type that increments in .75 but has a default value of 3.2

would it be?

```
pounds_lifted decimal(2,1)default '2.5' NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Identity column pounds_lifted must be of data type `INT`, `BIGINT`, `SMALLINT`, `TINYINT`, `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` with a **scale of 0**, and constrained to be nonnullable